# How do I send tableview data on submit button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, model

I have a `UITableView` with 2 sections.

Each section has different xib cells (with multiple textfields, radio buttons etc.).

The user can enter those values using the keyboard.

How can I get the value of each text field at submit button using model?

Here is my model class for cell **for detail section**:

[image]

```
class DataModel {    
    var name: String?
    var gender: String?


    init(name: String?, gender: String?)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender 
    }
}
```

How I use it in my tableview:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"DetailCell") as? DetailCell
                     if cell == nil{
                         let arrNib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DetailCell",owner: self, options: nil)!
                         cell = arrNib.first as? DetailCell
                     }
                 let model: DataModel

                   model = DataModel [indexPath.row]

                   //displaying values
                   cell?.name_lbl.text = model.name
                   cell?.gender_lbl.text = model.gender



              return cell!
}
```

Comment: xib cell classes implemented delegate, pass model to cell populate data in cell and then save data there in model

Comment: hi thanks but can you please share bit code wise ?

Comment: where is the submit button? Inside the cell or in the view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you name_lbl and gender_lbl shoule be UITextField, not the UILabel.
You have to add target for the name_lbl and gender_lbl:

```
cell?.name_lbl.text = model.name
cell?.name_lbl.tag = indexPath.section
cell?.name_lbl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldNameDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
cell?.gender_lbl.text = model.gender 
cell?.name_lbl.tag = indexPath.section
cell?.name_lbl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldGenderDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
```

and you add methods textFieldNameDidChange and textFieldGenderDidChange as:

```
@objc func textFieldGenderDidChange(sender: UITextField) { 
     var model = DataModel[sender.tag]
     model.gender = sender.text
}
```

You should do the same for the "name".

Comment: var model = DataModel[sender.tag]

It crash ?

Answer (score 1):

You can give tag to textfield and use UITextFieldDelegate for this like,

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 0 {
       model.name = textField.text ?? ""
    }
}
```

on you button submit, you can access model value like

```
 @IBAction func submitButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    let name = model.name
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For this u need to set tag to textfield in cell for row. In shouldChageCharacter delegate method set text to data array with respective indexpath and create the object of uitableviewcell and set text to the respective label. for get data you can get data from array. In above answer may be if u scroll table then TableCell will mix with eachother.